# How to drag down value based on common column value

Tags: excel, draggable

I am looking to drag down the discount code from an order for each of the line items for that specific order number.

Example:
This is what I have from the export:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs150.png)

I am hoping there is an easy way to do this with a formula and not manually for each order record.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntCs6.png)

All of the 12345 orders would need a code of AE, while the order code 54321 would not need anything dragged down.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried ? Simple IF Function should work like this --> `=IF($A2=12345,"AE","")` and fill down!

Comment: And if you select all the cells where that if() needs to be entered, then type or paste it and finish with ctrl+Enter then Excel writes in all the cells. But cmnd+D also works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

```
=IF(A2=12345,"AE","") //wrote in B1 cell, and apply to B3---B11
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is some basic approaches, which i have learnt from here, sharing with you as well,

1.) `=IFS($A2=12345,"AE",$A2=54321,"")`

2.) `=IF($A2=12345,"AE","")`

3.) `=SWITCH($A2,12345,"AE","")`

4.) `=IFERROR(CHOOSE(($A2=12345)/1,"AE",),"")`

5.) `=LOOKUP(A2,{12345,54321},{"AE",""})`

6.) `=VLOOKUP($A2,{12345,"AE";54321,""},2,0)`

7.) `=XLOOKUP($A2,{12345,54321},{"AE",""})`

8.) `=FILTER("AE",$A2=12345,"")`

Use any one of the either & **Fill Down +**, but you should have google searched a bit or you could searched here, ample of resources!

[image: BASIC FORMULAS]

Comment: There are going to be numerous order numbers. Not just 12345 and 54321. Those are just examples. There are hundreds of order numbers so a simple if statement won’t work. 
The first order number will have the code if it was applied. So I need to apply it to all of the same order number. If the order number set doesn’t have the code, then the code won’t be applied.

Comment: @BetsyBoyle i apologize for the same, since the image which you have shared, everyone including me assumed that you might have only two codes, however i had some doubts, still, i said simple IF! Well in that scenario, you may create a table of reference for those Order Number which have a code, and then you can use a `VLOOKUP` or `XLOOKUP` or any lookup function to do the task, the one which will not be found shall show you an error which you can parse by using either `IFNA` or `IFERROR` Function!

Comment: @BetsyBoyle since you have also mentioned about it will be numerous order numbers, so how do you determine the one should have a code ? It will be much helpful, if you be more precise on it! I will be glad to help you out!

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
It’s completely random. 
Basically, If someone places an order, they put in a specific code for a discount. But the code will only show up on one of the order numbers if there are multiple items in that order. If they did not place the order using the discount code, the code won’t show. Right now, I’m manually dragging the code down for each specific order that the code was used for. If that doesn’t make sense, I can try and create another table example.

Comment: @BetsyBoyle madam, is it acceptable if there is an extra column for the formula, which you need to drag down, & this should work since you have mentioned that the code will show up on one of the numbers if there are multiple items for that specific order <https://imgur.com/a/3N49CzA>

Comment: @BetsyBoyle So, Formula used in cell C2 where `Column A` --> `Order Number` ; `Column B` --> `Discount Code` entered once for a specific order number & `Column C` --> Formulated `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(($B$2:B2<>"")*($A$2:$A2=A2)),$B$2:B2),"")`

Comment: @BetsyBoyle madam, refer the answer, i have posted!

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i was referring to in the comments, you may use the formula in this way as well,

Formula used in cell C2

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(($B$2:B2<>"")*($A$2:$A2=A2)),$B$2:B2),"")
```

And Fill Down!!

[image: FORMULA]